# AWStats out result in a single html file?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, log-files, awstats

`AWStats` (`awstats_buildstaticpages.pl`) generates many htmls, e.g.

```
 awstats.mysite.alldomains.html
 awstats.mysite.allhosts.html
 awstats.mysite.allrobots.html
 awstats.mysite.browserdetail.html
 awstats.mysite.errors404.html
 awstats.mysite.html
 awstats.mysite.keyphrases.html
 awstats.mysite.keywords.html
 awstats.mysite.lasthosts.html
 awstats.mysite.lastrobots.html
 awstats.mysite.osdetail.html
 awstats.mysite.refererpages.html
 awstats.mysite.refererse.html
 awstats.mysite.session.html
 awstats.mysite.unknownbrowser.html
 awstats.mysite.unknownip.html
 awstats.mysite.unknownos.html
 awstats.mysite.urldetail.html
 awstats.mysite.urlentry.html
 awstats.mysite.urlexit.html
```

Is there an option to output in a single large html, instead of 20 html files?

EDIT: Basically, what I want is `awstats_buildstaticpages.pl` to output a single html instead of many html files.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

> Is there a way to merge all the html reports into a single html?

`cat` can do that:

```
$ cat awstats.mysite.*.html > awstats.mysite.html
```

---

Just use `-output`:

```
perl awstats.pl -config=mysite -output -staticlinks > awstats.mysite.html
```

instead of `-output=x`:

```
perl awstats.pl -config=mysite -output=alldomains -staticlinks > awstats.mysite.alldomains.html
perl awstats.pl -config=mysite -output=allhosts -staticlinks > awstats.mysite.allhosts.html
```

Comment: Use `-output` alone outputs only the main report, but does not output other detail reports (e.g. keyphrases, keywords, etc.). Is there a way to merge all the html reports into a single html?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `cat` *.html does not update links (to other external htmls) within the main html (awstats.mysite.html) though.